# What is the difference between "deploying" and "distribution"?

Tags: difference

For instance, in development environment, I would like to know that when should I say:

> The app is ready for deploying.

and

> The app is ready for distribution.

If they are the same from development viewpoint, what about the real life?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about software? Or by "real life" do you mean to include things like merchandise or military battalions?  You should also consult a good dictionary to get a sense of the meanings of the verbs and nouns distribute, distribution, deploy, deployment.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo "Are you asking specifically about software?" Yes I am, please advice.

Comment: It should be *deployment*, not *deploying*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In software, if you *distribute* an application, you send it out to all the end users.  Mobile and PC applications, that each user has to install individually, can be *distributed*.

> Our app is in iTunes and approved for **distribution**.

If you *deploy* an application, you get it running on the device or server where the end users will access it.  For example, web applications, that run from a centralized location and are remotely accessed, can be *deployed*.

> We're ready to **deploy** the latest built to QA.  Once it passes the tests, we can **deploy** to Prod.

Especially with mobile applications, many use *deploy* to indicate the application is both *sent out* to end users, and *set up* on their devices.  This is probably why you are confused.

*Distribution* sends the app out to the users; *deployment* makes sure each has a running version.

Comment: Thanks for the nice well-described answer. May I wait for other answers before accepting yours :)

Comment: @AhmadF  Yes of course.  Someone might provide an even better answer.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Items can be **distributed** to their users or locations to be stored until they are **deployed** for use.

These words have similar meaning and I am sure there are overlaps. **Distribution** is about passing things out, or delivering them. **Deploying** is about making use of things.

Answer (score 2):

In software, they mean **similar but meaningfully different** things.

**Distribution** means sending the package (however it is packaged) to a destination location.  What happens at the destination is not specifically described.

**Deploy** means to send the software to a specific target or targets and put it in a *running state*.

Answer (score 1):

A distributed app would be an installer that you let others download.  The end user must install it and configure it.

A deployed app is one that you distribute and setup and configure.   A web app can be said to be deployed because once it goes live anyone can use it immediately, whereas a program installer would be distributed since the end user must click on and run the installer.